# telegram bot proxy in python

Tags: python, proxy, telegram, telegram-bot, pysocks

I am using Telebot to make a python bot for Telegram

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot('TokenHere')
apihelper.proxy = {'https': 'socks5://user:password@127.0.0.1:1080'}
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Hello?")
```

I have a latest version installed: gunicorn, PySocks, pyTelegramBotAPI, requests and urllib3

still receive error:

```
AssertionError: Not supported proxy scheme socks5
```

Proxy works fine i checked it with another bot.

Comment: make sure you've the latest version of pysocks. run `pip install -U pysocks` and see if it works

Comment: Requirement already up-to-date: pysocks in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (1.7.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just deleted a python-requests via yum, and installed via pip